# AWS Cognito Userpool via cloudformation file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to code my cognito userpools as cloudformation templates. I am running into one open question however: how to define standard attributes? Will Cognito know that `birthdate` in `Schema` is meant to be the standard birthdate - and validate it as such? How is the attribute `Schema` defined in the cloudformation template mapped to the standard, non-custom attributes like `email`, `birthdate`, ...?

More details: AWS Cognito separates between standard attributes and custom attributes. This separation is amongst other things important because standard attributes are validated for their format: `email` and `birthdate` for example accept only an AWS defined, specific format.

Thus my question: how does AWS Cognito map the cloudformation `Schema` defined attributes to standard AWS Cognito attributes? Does it at all, and if so by identity of the attribute name?

Also see:

[AWS Cognito Cloudformation Schema](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute.html)

Example created by someone: [Cloudformation example](https://gist.github.com/singledigit/2c4d7232fa96d9e98a3de89cf6ebe7a5)

Comment: Be careful when updating schema via cloudformation though, it will redeploy your whole userpool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the SchemaAttributes property. For standard attributes they must be named according to the Open ID Connect specification -

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html

By doing this they will map appropriately and you can set other properties on the property such as Required. It appears the docs need to be updated to make this more clear.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute.html

Comment: Thank you, but to my understanding this does not solve my issue. First: there are only `Schema` and `AliasAttributes` properties, I assume you are speaking of these. Now `AliasAttributes` supports only 3 values for phone, mail, username - to my understanding intended for cases where you want aliases. Which I don't - my question more simply put: how to define _standard_ attributes? Will Cognito know that `birthdate` in `Schema` is meant to be the standard `birthdate` - and validate it as such?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Due to the convoluted namings I am still not sure if we understand each other. On the root level of the `AWS::Cognito::UserPool` resource in cloudformation you only have `Schema` and `AliasAttributes`. Now `Schema` is a list of `SchemaAttributes`. Thus your answer is what I am implying in my question: that `SchemaAttributes` will be mapped by their name to the standard attributes - and validated accordingly.

Comment: Correct. You need to map each standard Cognito attribute by setting the SchemaAttribute's name to the standard name of the attribute following the Open ID Connect standard naming, as is shown in the two links I provided. Does that help clarify?

Comment: I had to try this a few times, so just wanted to summarize this to save anyone else a few minutes. This was exactly what I wanted though.

If you want to say make 'email' a standard attribute 'required', add it under Properties > Schema and use Name: 'email' (from openid) like they said

Comment: Do you need to define every standard attribute in `Schema`? In order to be able to use them in an `AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient`'s `ReadAttributes`

Comment: What an absolute travesty of documentation. Thanks for your explanation!